# Amazon Affiliate API: How to get product variations

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-product-api, affiliate

I'm trying to get product variation from Amazon Affiliate API without success.

In order to show an example you can see [this page](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B010OCASR8) 
There is a range of prices and different colors.
If I do an ItemLookup of the itemId B00RW59UKC I receive only information about a single product with size 42.5.

How could I get information about the same product in different colors and sizes?

Answer (score 1):

you can find it if you included the correct response group (eg, Medium,Offers,VariationMatrix)

in the response xml, you can get :

$parent_ASIN    = $oProdcut->Items->Item->ParentASIN;

then  to count how many different attribute (color, size, etc..):

$parent->Items->Item->Variations->VariationDimensions->VariationDimension;
$varAttributeCount  = count($VariationDimension);

hope this helps.

Comment: in my case i was using child ASIN id instead of parent